# How to get Literal from sqarqlResultset - dotnerRdf

Tags: c#, semantic-web, dotnetrdf

I get a result from query bellow, how I get 18.
|
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqQ2A.png) |
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4AD9.png)

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not for writing your code, you have to provide some own affords to get help.

Comment: sr, i think my question easy to imagin, i had add image of source code

Comment: @ThiệnSinh even if it is easy to imagine, it is your job to make it easier for us to provide you with an answer - remember, we are doing it for free. And please use the editor to insert your code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SparqlResult` rows have value nodes: https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Querying%20with%20SPARQL#!accessing-values:

```
INode value = r.Value("var");
```

Value nodes can be type-checked and cast to a literal node that have `Value` properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40049736/464590

```
    if (value is ILiteralNode)
    {
        var literal = value as ILiteralNode;
        Console.WriteLine(literal.Value);
    }
```